# tcpkill: finish connections only after they're ESTABLISHED

Tags: tcp, google-compute-engine, postman, tcpdump

For testing purpose, I need to send POST requests to Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer from Postman with Google Developer Tools enabled (tracking network activity).

Every request should be made with a different connection.

So, I suppose to use `tcpkill` utility:

`$ tcpkill -9 "dst XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and dst port 443"`

But, eventually, this leads to closing every connection before it would be established. So, Postman gets a connection error.

So, the question is: how to finish connection only after it was ESTABLISHED and POST request was sent to the server?

Thanks in advance, comrades.

Comment: Why do you want to kill the connections? If you really want to do that, then you can check connections in ESTABLISHED or some other later state using netstat, lsof, ss, etc, first and then kill only those ones.

Comment: @LucianoAfranllie The thing is that I just want tcpkill to stay running in the terminal for instantly killing connections, but if I make a request after tcpkill started, the connection won't reach to the server at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with tcpkill since this program requires traffic to kill the connection and does not support filters using connection state. So, if you run tcpkill before the connections are established, they will be killed before connecting; and if you run tcpkill after connections are established they won't be killed if there is no traffic since tcpkill requires a valid sequence number to send a RST.

You can try [killcx](http://killcx.sourceforge.net/) filtering established connections with ss or netstat, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dst=$1
port=$2

peer_addrs=$(ss -t state established dst ${dst} dport = :${port} | 
tail -n +2 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d : -f 1)
for addr in ${peer_addrs}; do
    echo "killing ${addr}:${port}"
    killcx ${addr}:${port}" &
    sleep 2
    killall -9 killcx
done
```

You will need to run this script periodically in a loop using watch or similar and, of course, this won't kill connections immediately after they are established but a little bit later when the cycle finds the connection.

Comment: tcpkill supports TCP flags like tcpdump do: `tcpkill "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) != 0" `. Maybe, I could use something like this to prevent the killing of connections, that just going to become established. Also, tcpkill would do so-called "kill" to the established connection, as it sends RST flag to it (AFAIK).

Comment: With tcpdump expressions the best you can do is to watch for a SYN/ACK packet but not for the last ACK actually establishing the connection since it is not different to any other ACK. Regarding your last comment, tcpkill can kill established connections only after seeing some traffic on that connection, its need traffic to get a valid sequence number for the RST.

Comment: I think, I'd write a script with expect, which would loop waiting for a string in the netstat command output with ESTABLISHED status, and would kill that only connection by the src port. LGTM.